# How do I preview wordpress site locally on VScode?

Tags: wordpress, visual-studio-code, woocommerce, preview

I'm very new, thank you in advance

I have a **WooCommerce** webpage running on **WordPress** that recently took from my developer, I'm working on *VScode* and looking for an option to preview code changes locally, before uploading everything back. I've tried running some index.php files on the live console but all I get is a raw explorer version of the site (showing all folders and data).

I did HTML a while ago and remember it was as easy as double-clicking the .html file, but I haven't figured out this yet.